# Inserting a variable amidst another variable

Tags: java, swing, variables

I have three textboxes ct1,ct2,ct3. I have to use a for loop 1 to 3 and check whether the textboxes are empty. So, inside the for loop, how do I represent it? For example,

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    if(ct+i.getText()) // I know I'm wrong
     {
     }

}
```

Comment: Use an array. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have three textboxes ct1,ct2,ct3.

There's your problem to start with. Instead of using three separate variables, create an array or collection:

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = new TextBox[3];
// Populate the array...
```

Or:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new ArrayList<TextBox>();
// Populate the list...
```

Then in your loop:

```
// Note the < here - not <=
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   // If you're using the array
   String text = textBoxes[i].getText();

   // or for the list...
   String text = textBoxes.get(i).getText();
}
```

Or if you don't need the index:

```
for (TextBox textBox : textBoxes) {
    String text = textBox.getText();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sir, what is the package I should import for the Class TextBox?

Answer (score 2):

Use an array

```
TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[]{ct1,ct2,ct3};
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    boxes[i].getText(""); // I know I'm wrong
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your text boxes in a list and iterate over that list:

```
List<TextBox> ctList = new ArrayList<TextBox> ();
list.add(ct1);
list.add(ct2);
list.add(ct3);

for (TextBox ct : ctList) {
    if(ct.getText().equals("expected text")) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, what is the package I should import for the Class TextBox?

Comment: @Gomathi You said *"I have three textboxes ct1,ct2,ct3"* so you need to replace `TextBox` in this example by the type of those objects (maybe a `JTextField` or `JTextArea`?).