# Variables including loop counter in name

Tags: java

So I have this code, where `en1` is an instance of a object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    System.out.println("Introduce el nombre de una empresa");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    en1.setName(scanner.next());
}
```

I would like to change the 1 on `en1` to the loop counter. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a variable amidst another variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775768/inserting-a-variable-amidst-another-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an Array and have each element correspond to the iteration of the loop.

```
//Instantiation 
Enterprise[] en = new Enterprise[20];//the number of iterations you need

//You do not have a default constructor, so I would use this to add the "int index"
en[i] = new Enterprise(X); //For each enterprise where "X" is a number for the "int index"


//in the loop
en[i].setName(scanner.next());
```

The array in my example will have 20 elements (0 through 19).  Each one can correspond to a single iteration.  There is no way to change the name of a variable based on other variables.

Comment: en is not a string. It is an object.

Comment: A object from a class. Here is the class code. Sorry the text is in spanish. http://pastebin.com/gUCWRRgK

Answer (score 11):

Try using an array

```
 en[i].setName (scanner.next ());
```

Comment: Can I use an array of an object?

Comment: You can use an array of references to objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the names of parameters using variables in Java. Like the other user suggested, make an array of en objects and access each individual object using the loop counter. This way is much cleaner and idiomatic.